# min and max Variadic Template variant in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, initializer-list, stl-algorithm

Am I right in reading the standard that from `min` and `max` (and `minmax` for that matter) there are new **initializer_list** variants, but no **Variadic Template** variants?

Thus, this is ok:

```
int a = min( { 1,2,a,b,5 } );
```

but this is not:

```
int b = min( 1,2,a,b,5 ); // err!
```

I guess, many people would expect that Variadic Templates could have easily implemented this, therefore they might be disappointed.

I'd say that using V.T. for `min` and `max` would be overkill

- *variadic templates* are capable of handling multiple types
- *initializer lists* check that all types are the same by design

therefore I.L. are much better suited for the task.

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.  [N2772](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2772.pdf) contains more in-depth rationale.

Comment: All very nice but if one has a variadic set still someone has to do the conversion to `std::initializer_list` to a "common type" find (and find a good convention to figure out the "common type" for the purpose of minimization).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using variadic templates with and without **Boost Concepts Common Type Traits** for `min` tested on GCC 4.6. I'm not sure if common_type this is need or not, though.

```
#define LessThanComparable class
#include <boost/type_traits/common_type.hpp>


/*! Multi-Type Minimum of \p a. */
template <LessThanComparable T> const T & multi_type_min (const T & a) { return a; } // template termination
/*! Multi-Type Minimum of \p a, \p b and \p args. */
template <class T, class ... R >
//requires SameType <T , Args >...
T multi_type_min(const T & a, const T & b, const R &... args)
{
    return multi_type_min(a < b ? a : b, args...);
}

/*! Minimum of \p a. */
template <LessThanComparable T> const T & min(const T & a) { return a; } // template termination
/*! Minimum of \p a, \p b and \p args. */
template <class T, class U, class ... R, class C = typename boost::common_type<T, U, R...>::type >
C min(const T & a, const U & b, const R &... c)
{
    return min(static_cast<C>(a < b ? a : b), static_cast<C>(c)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think it's fair to say that having all the values be of compatible types makes lists a good candidate for this feature.  That's not to say that you couldn't write your own variadic template version.

Comment: "couldn't" or "wouldn't" :-) Yes, probably, possibly. I dont't know if one should. For the expression `max(1,2, 3.1415, 4)` I can image all kinds of things i want the compiler to do... like casting all `int` to `double`, or all `double` to `int`. If I saw a template that would recursivly try to implement this... I don't know If I would trust it.

Answer (score 0):

By combining the variadic template and initializer_list, we can let the function `int b = min( 1,2,a,b,5 );` works without recursive unfolding.

```
template <class T>
T _real_min_(T a, std::initializer_list<T> s) {
    T *res = &a;
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it) {
        *res = *(it) < *res ? *it : *res;
    }
    return *res;
}

template <class T, class... ArgTypes>
T min(T a, ArgTypes... args) {
  return _real_min_(a, {args...});
}
```